# Sed: How do I get a phone number in the form (ddd)-ddd-dddd?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file containing a bunch of text and I need to replace every phone number in the form (ddd)-ddd-dddd with dddddddddd. How do I do this? My first guess is that it will look something like:

```
s/\(\\\(ddd\\\)\)-ddd-dddd/\1\2\3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/(\([0-9]*\))-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)/\1\2\3/' file
```

OR using extended regex flag:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/\(([0-9]{3})\)-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{4})/\1\2\3/' file
```

Comment: POSIX variant 's/\(([0-9]\{3\})\)-([0-9]\{3\})-([0-9]\{4\})/\1\2\3/g' (with the ending g because there is maybe more than 1 phone number on some lines)

Comment: Thanks! But could you please explain the '-i.bak' option? I know -i is for in-place, but what about the .bak part?

Comment: `.bak` is name of the backup extension sed will create before in-line editing the file. This is just for safety if anything goes wrong your original file can be found with `file.bak` name.

Comment: -i.bak means backup your original file as file.bak